# Why bootstrap is not working in small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am developing an app using bootstrap but this is not all working in small screens.This works perfectly in big screens like that of PC browser but when I open it in mobile browser then none of the tab gets opened.i am not opening the fiddle in mobile.In the pc browser i open the app as localhost:8080/sms Then this app gets opened up with all tabs functioning properly.If I do this in similar way in mobile localhost:8080/sms then only the default tab is working because the class is active.But nothing happens when you click on the tabs.Even this app is not working in fiddle small `screen`.

http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/251/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div id="myModal">` is being displayed above your tabs when the screen gets smaller making them unclickable.

The .fade class on your modal is not enough to hide it

I updated it like this `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade hide"`

I added thie .hide class

here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/256/

Comment: Not a single tab is working in small screen,<div id="myModal"> is not working by default,If possible please give a fiddle

Comment: do you know this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561661/ok-button-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker